# express project running on the server but could not get any response

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean, devops

[image]

My express server seems okay in the host. But I try to access an endpoint using `IP:PORT/something`. I didn't get nothing. Even I didn't get any `500` error.

POSTMON says
[image]

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Where is your server hosted?

Comment: Open the traffic for that port https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image you have uploaded, it looks like your server is hosted on `AWS EC2`. Since you are not even able to reach your node server, it looks like you haven't added that port(on which it is hosted) in the inbound rules of your EC2 security group.

You need to **open that port for all IPs** (if you want it to access form anywhere)  or specific IP, if you want to access only from your specific IP.

Please read it in detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

**Update**

If you are using Digital Ocean, you can open the access to that port in the `firewall rules`.

To open a custom `Port` for inbound access, you need to add `custom Rules` in firewall.

**From official Docs**

> **Protocol**. You can choose either TCP or UDP. Because ICMP has no port
>   abstraction, to allow ICMP traffic, you select it directly from the
>   New rule dropdown.
>
> **Port Range**. For the TCP and UDP protocols, you can specify:
>
> - A single port.
> - A range of ports by entering the starting and ending ports separated    by a dash - with no spaces, e.g. 3000-4000. To open
>     multiple    non-sequential ports, create a separate rule for each.
> - All ports by leaving the field blank.
>
> **Sources** for inbound rules, which
>   lets you restrict the source of incoming connections.
>
> **Destinations** for outbound rules, which lets you restrict the
>   destination of outgoing connections.
>
> You can limit the sources/destinations to:
>
> Droplets, chosen by name, IP address, or tag DigitalOcean Load
>   Balancers, chosen by name, IP address, or tag Non-DigitalOcean servers
>   by IP addresses, subnets, or CIDR ranges.

[image: Image From Firebase official Docs]

Please read about how to configure firewall rules in Digital Ocean, in their [official Documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/how-to/configure-rules/)

If you directly want to jump to Adding Custom Rules, read [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/how-to/configure-rules/#custom-rules)

Comment: I am using digital ocean. Also I didn't installed any server Apache or ngnix. The tutorial I refer is not used Apache or something. But some other tutorials I see that I have to install a server. Do I really install a server?

Comment: You can still add the firewall inbound rules in Digital ocean as well, you dont need to host it anywhere else, just add the firewall rules